# On infinite groups that is not Simple

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$  be an infinite group , $e\neq x\in G$ and the conjugate class of $x$ has finitely many elements. Prove that $G$ is not a simple group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By hypothesis you have that your group $G$ acts on the conjugate class of $x$ which is a finite set, let call $n$ the cardinality of this set. 
So $G$ acts on this set of $n$ element, this gives us an homomorphism $\varphi \colon G \to S_n$, where $S_n$ is the group of permutation on $n$-elements. Clearly this homomorphism cannot be injective, because $G$ is infinite while $S_n$ has just $n!$ elements, so this homomorphism must have a non trivial kernel which is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: This doesn't cover the case $n=1$.

Comment: That case $\,n=1\,$ is trivial, @ChrisEagle, as $\,|Conj(x)|=1\Longleftrightarrow x\in Z(G)\,$,  but since $\,x\neq e\,$ then this would mean $\,1\neq Z(G)\triangleleft G\,$ and we're done.

Comment: @ChrisEagle You're right, but it seems that DonAntonio beat me in time. Anyway thank you both to helping me improving the answer. :)

Comment: @DonAntonio May I know is it possible that $G=Z(G)$?

Comment: @AlanWang In that case then $\;G\;$ is abelian and certainly non-simple...